# Hbase scan not returning all rows when setting heigher value in scan.setCaching(cacheRow)

Tags: hbase

```
    Scan s = new Scan();
    s.addFamily(Bytes.toBytes("cf1"));
    s.setCaching(cacheRows);
    s.setCacheBlocks(false);
    s.setStartRow("30.0.2.2\01441756800\0");
    s.setStopRow("30.0.2.3\01441756800\0");

    ResultScanner scanner = table.getScanner(s);

    long rows = 0;
    try {
        for (Result rr = scanner.next(); rr != null; rr = scanner.next()) {
            rows++;
        }
    } finally {
        scanner.close();
    }

    System.out.println("Total no of rows = " + rows);
```

When I run above code with cacheRows = 100 or 10000 it prints 
Total no of rows = 480000

When I run above code with cacheRows = 100000 it prints 
Total no of rows = 10090

cacheRows = 10083 prints 480000

cacheRows = 10084 prints 191595

cacheRows = 10085 prints 20169

cacheRows = 10086 prints 20170

cacheRows = 10087 prints 20171

cacheRows = 10088 prints 20172

cacheRows = 10089 prints 20173

cacheRows = 10090 prints 20174

cacheRows >= 10091 prints 10090

Answer (score 5):

Issue was resolved 
by setting same *hbase.server.scanner.max.result.size* and *hbase.client.scanner.max.result.size* in hbase-site.xml 
OR
by setting setMaxResultSize in scan object value equal to size of 100000(caching rows argument) rows which was 20971520 (20MB) in my case
Please see bug for more details: [HBASE-13527](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HBASE-13527)